# How can I sort NTEXT column in SQL Server with data like 1.1abc,1.2,1.10,2.1abc,2.2cdf

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, natural-sort

My column contains alphanumeric values having difference in length. How can I sort in ascending order without using hierarchyid? I need to sort the values in

```
1.1 abc
1.2 abd
1.10 abc
```

Comment: A `varchar` doesn't have the same order as a numerical data type. This seems like the above should be 3 columns not 1; is this something you can fix? Could you have more than 2 components in your value at the start? I.e. the string `'1.11.2'`?

Comment: above 3 values are from same column, i need to sort the same column having alphanumeric characters

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions...

Comment: Are those version numbers?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: If I get this correctly, you will have to split this in fragments and sort column after column. the second approach is to split this and fill each fragment to a specified length (e.g. `0001.0001 abc and 0001.0010 abc`. This wil allow for alphanumeric sorting. And btw: `NTEXT` is outdated for almost 20 years now...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),field)` . 
Replace `field` with your field name

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),field), '.', '')
```

Comment: If i sort using the above code i will get **1.1a,1.10a,1.2a**. I need **1.1a,1.2a,1.10a**

Comment: You are using string sort, and it's different with number sort

Answer (score 0):

You are doing three nonstandard thing as I see it

1. Ntext is deprecated, convert it to nvarchar(max)
2. You are cramming different content into one column
3. You are sorting in a nonstandard way. as numeric 1.10=1.1

To make this owrk you need to
Convert to working data type
Split you string into 3 parts
sort by part and 2 as numeric and part 3 as character

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
    DirtyCol NTEXT
)
INSERT INTO @table
    VALUES ('1.1 abc')
    , ('1.2 abd')
    , ('1.10 abc')

SELECT
    CleanCol
   ,CAST(LEFT(CleanCol, dot - 1) AS INT) s1
   ,CAST(SUBSTRING(CleanCol, dot + 1, spc - dot - 1) AS INT) s2
   ,SUBSTRING(CleanCol, spc + 1, LEN(CleanCol) - spc) s3
FROM @table
OUTER APPLY (SELECT
        CAST(DirtyCol AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) CleanCol
       ,CHARINDEX('.', DirtyCol) dot
       ,CHARINDEX(' ', DirtyCol) spc) a
ORDER BY CAST(LEFT(CleanCol, dot - 1) AS INT)
, CAST(SUBSTRING(CleanCol, dot + 1, spc - dot - 1) AS INT)
, SUBSTRING(CleanCol, spc + 1, LEN(CleanCol) - spc)
```

Here I use an outer apply to convert the colun to nvarchar(max), and to calculate to heæper values, the posistion of the "." and the " " in you string

Using the converted string, and the placement of these I can seperate the string into the first integer, the second interger and the string [s1,s2,s3]
I convert the first two to integer and sort by s1,s2,s3

Result is

```
+----------+----+----+-----+
| cleancol | s1 | s2 | s3  |
+----------+----+----+-----+
| 1.1 abc  |  1 |  1 | abc |
| 1.2 abd  |  1 |  2 | abd |
| 1.10 abc |  1 | 10 | abc |
+----------+----+----+-----+
```

You do not need to include s1,s2 and s3 in the results, just in the sort